# How to remove classes separately one by one with if statements and .each() loop in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope somebody can help me with looping through a list and removing classes one by one based on the value of a variable.

I'm making a game where there are 3 star icons shown. I want them to disappear one by one depending on how many moves you used to try and solve the puzzle. Right now it is removing them all at once. I'm running into issues using the break statement because it is breaking my onclick which runs the puzzle game.

Any suggestions would be great! Thank you for your time in advance!

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="score-panel">
    <ul class="stars">
        <i class="panel1 fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="panel2 fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="panel3 fa fa-star"></i>
    </ul>

    <span class="moves">0</span> Moves
</section>
```

Here's my Javascript and jQuery:

```
$('.stars').children().each(function (index, element) {
    if (moves === 16) {
        $(this).removeClass();
    } else if (moves === 24) {
        $(this).removeClass();
    } else if (moves === 32) {
        $(this).removeClass();
    }
});
```

Comment: why do you need if else you are removing same class anyway

Comment: `<i>` is not a valid element as a child of `<ul>` — were you thinking of `<li>`?

Comment: you want to remove a class based on the value inside span rite?
if so than here is your solution 

**$('.stars').children().each(function (index, element) {

var moves = parseInt($('.moves').text());
            if (moves === 16) {
                $(this).removeClass('panel1');
            } else if (moves === 24) {
                $(this).removeClass('panel2');
            } else if (moves === 32) {
                $(this).removeClass('panel3');
            }
        });**

Comment: Thank you Pointy! What if I wrap each ```<i>``` element in a ```<li>```?

Comment: guradio, I want to remove the class of "panel1 fa fa-star" when moves reach 16. Then once moves reach 24 then I want to remove class of "panel2 fa fa-star".  Right now it's just removing them all at once!

Comment: Your logic is wrong, you remove everything because you said so! Each means that every child gets this logic, so every star will be removed when `moves` variable is equal to 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for logic like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h10Lewyt/

```
var moves = 0;
var movesToMakeForDeletionOfStar = [16, 24, 32];

$('#moveCounter').click(function () {
    moves++;
  $('#moves').text('moves ' + moves);
  if($.inArray(moves, movesToMakeForDeletionOfStar) > -1) {
    $('.stars').children().last().remove();
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michelangelo! I ended up doing something similar to this and using an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery .last() function in this manner.

```
$('.stars.fa').last().removeClass();
```